# Element Not Interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

### Edit:

I solved it by doing a `find_elements_by_xpath` and then using a `try, catch` for all elements till no error and break.

### To anyone reading this question. I tried every solution here and it didn't work. The solutions were correct, the error or problem was there were multiple elements with the same xpath.
By selecting the the first element I was selecting something which was not interactable.

Getting an error when trying to `click` or `send_keys` to an `input` element.

```
st = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@id, "st")]')
# Element found
st.send_keys(str(amt))
# Error element not interactable
st.click()
# error element not interactable
```

The element:

```
<input id="st" type="text" value="" maxlength="7" tabindex="0">
```

I am able to interact and send keys to another element in the same row as this on the webpage.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)
```

Any idea on how to solve or why I am running into this error?

Comment: Can you try and interact with the element using 'id'?

Comment: @BuddyBobIII I tried right now and get the same error.

Comment: We can't tell why the element isn't interactable from this code. Can you paste the HTML fo ryour page?

Comment: Please can you post whole section of this code? Sometimes the developer uses things like span to restrict input area, making whole input uninteractable. Kindly provide the whole section and not just the line. For a basic change, can you try adding `time.sleep(5)` just to remove the possibility that element does not load in time. Thank You.

Comment: Add html code to your question

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the exact reason why the element is not interacting but you can add text to input box using JavaScript. There is a class in Selenium which allows to execute JavaScript code in browser. Do somethin like this:

```
script = "arguments[0].value="+str(amt)
driver.execute_script(script,st)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",st)
```

This will set the value of input box to the given string.

In C#:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string script = "arguments[0].value="+amt.toString();
js.executeScript(script,st)
//to click
js.executScript("arguments[0].click()",st)
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Even `execute_script` may not always work.

Comment: But in most of the cases it do work where Selenium fails to do so. I even have clicked on a drop down option link without click on the drop down(drop down list to view on page) with JavaScript.

Comment: In 90% of cases it will probably work. It works for me, but sometimes I have to look for other workarounds

Comment: So what other alternatives you use?

Comment: @MuhammadSuleman Thanks, I haven't been able to test the script as yet. I will update asap. Am I correct in assuming the code is directly setting the attribute `value` to `amt`?

Comment: @Sid sure no problem. Yes, it will directly set the value of input type to given string.